# Php and javascript reading issue

Tags: javascript, php, linux, chmod, chown

I have an issue in my web interface and I need your help.. I seperate my php code and javascript in two files it runs well using wamp server but when I test my code on my server it didn't work so i think my index.php cannot read script.js so what could be the problem?

This what i have in my folder:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  240 2015-05-31 17:24 saveFile.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7186 2015-05-31 17:26 script.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2015-05-31 17:28 upload
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6300 2015-05-31 17:29 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  217 2015-06-02 09:50 config.php
```

index.php including script.js

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php $cur_dir = explode('\\', getcwd());?>
    <script src="/<?php echo $cur_dir[count($cur_dir)-1] . '/';?>script.js"></script>
    <script>
```

Comment: is there a reason your files are all under root?

Comment: We need to se the apache/nginx config (or what have you?) plus the code in index.php that includes the script.js

Comment: they took root by default

Comment: IIRC, you need not specify complete path if the JS file is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the web server cannot execute the php files. If you are using Ubuntu and Apache, try

`sudo chown www-data:www-data *`